# location of mysql database files when using direct admin to create the databases

Tags: linux, mysql, backup

I would like to know where the database files are located when using directadmin.
I use phpmyadmin to create the databases.
When I check /var/lib/mysql directory I cannot see the database I created.
But when I use the locate command, I found out the database is /var/lib/mysql.backup.
I find it odd.

Can somebody inform if the /var/lib/mysql.backup directory is where directadmin naturally store the databases created using phpmyadmin.
Or my mysql database is messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very much sure that no process could change the location of the DB files and they will be created only at the location where mysql data_dir is set.

So, if your mysql data directory is /var/lib/mysql, then any DB created by any way will be created into that directory only.

Comment: How do I know the data_dir value? - @GeekRide

Comment: Run this command on the MYSQL prompt ... `show variables like "datadir";`.

It will show you the value of data directory.